# Migration ResponseEntity to Mono<ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

In a spring boot application, I do a call to a ms with webclient

ResponseEntity response = webClient.post()
.uri("/auth/login")
.body(Mono.just(loginRequest), LoginDto.class)
.retrieve()
.toEntity(LoginResponse.class)
.block();

After I take roles and put it in a Collection

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = response.getBody().getRoles().stream()
            .map(item -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After I create a return a Mono

```
Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities));
```

I modified ms to return Mono<ResponseEntity> to be really reactive

With this change, I don't know what to change

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<LoginResponse>> response = webClient.post()
            .uri("/auth/login")
            .body(Mono.just(loginRequest), LoginDto.class)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(LoginResponse.class);

Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = response.getBody().getRoles().stream()
            .map(item -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use `flatMap` to map something to something else in an async way.

```
public Mono<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken> foobar() {
    Mono<ResponseEntity<LoginResponse>> response = webClient.post()
            .uri("/auth/login")
            .body(Mono.just(loginRequest), LoginDto.class)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(LoginResponse.class);

    return response.flatMap(response -> {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = response.getBody()
             .getRoles()
             .stream()
             .map(item -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(item))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities));
    }
}
```